# How to write code that checks to see if item is negative before split?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

Hey so I have a polyalphabetic cipher and it's working great but I am running into the issue of having all my inputs on one line. The inputs would be the shift;secretWord; and message. I need to find a way to check if an input is solely a negative number and if it is I need the code to exit. I also need to find a way to make my code keep looping until the negative condition is met.

```
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

shiftChange = 0
secretWord = 0
da_message = 0
shiftChange = int(shiftChange)
inputs = []

shiftChange, secretWord, da_message = input('').split(";") 
da_message = da_message.lower()
inputs.append(shiftChange)
inputs.append(secretWord)
inputs.append(da_message)

secretWord = secretWord.lower()
secretWord = secretWord * len(da_message)

cypherText = ''
symbol = ' '
count = 0
for letter in da_message:
   if letter in alpha:
       shift = alpha.index(secretWord[count]) + int(shiftChange)
       letterIndex = alpha.index(letter) + 1
       cypherLetter = alpha[(letterIndex+shift)%26]
       cypherText = cypherText + cypherLetter
       count = count + 1
       print(cypherText.upper())
```

Comment: `int()` tries to convert a string to a whole number. If it isn't a number, it raises a `ValueError`. Next step is then to test if number is less than `0`. Exiting code can be done with `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int()`.

The `int()` raises a ValueError for anything that isn't, entirely, an integer. Trap this error using a try-except loop and then if the error is raised, then execute the rest of your code. (since it is an alphanumeric) Otherwise, compare it if it is less than 0 and exit if true.

Below is a modified version of your code that solves both of your problems.
The `while True` ensures the program continues to loop until the negative number is found, which in turn causes it to exit the entire program.

```
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

shiftChange = 0
secretWord = 0
da_message = 0
cypherText = ''
symbol = ' '
count = 0
shiftChange = int(shiftChange)
inputs = []

while True:
    shiftChange, secretWord, da_message = input('enter:').split(";")
    da_message = da_message.lower()
    inputs.append(shiftChange)
    inputs.append(secretWord)
    inputs.append(da_message)
    secretWord = secretWord.lower()
    secretWord = secretWord * len(da_message)
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        try:
            temp = int(inputs[i])
        except ValueError:
            for letter in da_message:
               if letter in alpha:
                   shift = alpha.index(secretWord[count]) + int(shiftChange)
                   letterIndex = alpha.index(letter) + 1
                   cypherLetter = alpha[(letterIndex+shift)%26]
                   cypherText = cypherText + cypherLetter
                   count = count + 1
                   print(cypherText.upper())
        if temp < 0:
            exit()
```

Hope this helps!